# Update globally installed packages in `$GOPATH/bin`

Tags: go, go-modules

If I install a node package globally with `npm i -g aoeu`, I can update this package by running `npm update -g aoeu`, and I can update all my globally installed packages by running `npm update -g`.

Now, if I install a Go package to my `$GOPATH/bin` with `go install GitHub.com/aoeu@latest`, how can I update **all** these globally installed packages?

Comment: There is no record of what the binaries in your `bin/` directory are, they are just files on the filesystem. You need to record and/or update those manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, if I install a Go package to my $GOPATH/bin with go install GitHub.com/aoeu@latest, how can I update all these globally installed packages?

You can't, except to update each one individually.  There's no mechanism for this in Go. The files in this directory are not tracked in any way.